# получить слова заключенные между блоками

Tags: регулярные-выражения

есть текст типа `<--foo1-->text1<--foo2-->text2<--foo3-->text3`
как из этой строки получить строки text1, text2 и text3, то есть
в общем случае все строки заключенные между парами "тегов" или между "тегом" и концом строки

Данный код `/(?:\<--[\w]*--\>)([\w\W\s\S]+?)(?:\<--[\w]*--\>)/` отлавливает первое вхождение, но как заставить отловить оставшиеся

Comment: Такое выражение удовлетворяет ваш запрос?
https://regex101.com/r/gLVpL0/1

Comment: Спасибо, немного подправил ваш вариант, чтобы в отбор попал и последний блок: /
`-->(\w*)(?:<--|$)?
/
gm`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```
-->([\s\S]*?)(?:$|<--)
(?<=-->)[\s\S]*?(?=$|<--)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Q6ap2n/1).

**Подробности**

- `-->` - текст `-->`
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: 0 и более любых символов, как можно меньше
- `(?:$|<--)` - текст `(?:$|<--)`.

В случае с `(?<=-->)[\s\S]*?(?=$|<--)` захватывающая подмаска не нужна, так как 
`(?<=-->)` и  `(?=$|<--)` не добавляют найденный текст в буфер совпадения, а только проверяют на наличие этого текста до и после совпадения.